# java class working locally when imported in groovy script, but not when loaded into jenkins pipeline

Tags: java, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to use some java classes in a groovy script.
Locally, this works well: the classes are imported successfully, and when I run
the groovy script there are no errors.

But if I try to load the script into a jenkins scripted pipeline with

```
load('my_groovy_scripts_that_imports_local_java_classes')
```

it fails.
Jenkins complains that it can't find whatever package the groovy file imported (a java class), even though they're part f the same package locally, and locally it all works.

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:


Script1.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class j_stuff.testclass
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: The folder `j_stuff` where `testclass` is located must be in classpath

Comment: It is. I've set the CLASSPATH environment variable in the bashrc of the jenkins user. Also tried using the withenv method in the pipeline. Nothing works

Comment: just to be sure - `j_stuff` folder should not be a part of classpath. classpath should point to a folder that contains `j_stuff`. also in `testclass` there should be a `package j_stuff` declaration

Comment: yes. That's all correct. I'm now trying to see if I it works better when all the files are in a .jar instead. And also if I pass the path as an argument to jenkins by changing the jenkins configuration file in /etc/default/jenkins (--extraLibFolder)

Comment: ....and it still doesn't work. WOW.

Comment: It's crazy and ridiculous and impossible. I can't import a darn java class after trying everything and wasting a bunch of hours

Comment: BTW, I've also set groovy extra class paths from inside the jenkins interface (manage jenkins > global configuration) and still nothing

Comment: Sadly Jenkins is a pile of poo :( - it could be good if only they hadn't chosen Groovy